# .htaccess подмена url

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно выводить по адресу

```
http://site.ru/
```

содержимое

```
http://site.ru/main
```

но чтобы url в строке браузера оставался

```
http://site.ru/
```

Как это сделать в `.htaccess`?

**Обновление**

Имеется сайт, доступ к админке утерян (вариант с восстановлением доступа не предлогать), нужно заменить главную страницу сайта контентом с другой страницы, и чтобы URL оставался как будто это главная.

Comment: @CraftLawrence, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /main [L]
```

`^` - обозначает начало строки
`$` - обозначает конец строки
`RewriteRule ^$` - указывает на то, что правило действует только на главную страницу сайта (`^$` в данном случае означает пустую строку запроса)

`http://site.ru/` - подходит под эти условия. Здесь пустая строка запроса.
`http://site.ru/test/something` - не подходит. Строка запроса здесь - `test/something`.

Comment: Не работает. Страница открывается все так же, будто никаких записей в .htaccess и не производилось.

Comment: Выложите полныое содержание вашего .htaccess и адрес, который пытаетесь открыть. Возможно вы открыаете http://site.ru/index.php

Comment: Файл, можно сказать, пустой. Там только куча закомментированного текста.
Адрес http://feodosiya-otdih*точка*ru/

Comment: @CraftLawrence, и все-таки, покажите содержимое файла. В тестовом окружении код работает.

Comment: Вот ссылка на файл, который был в директории изначально:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6c92963203df/htaccess.txt (переименуйте в .htaccess)

Потому что тот, что сейчас, там две строчки закомментированного текста и код, который вы написали, и все.

Comment: @CraftLawrence, в том файле, помимо закоментированного текста, были еще и правила, которые срабатывали ДО указанного мной.  
Возможно, решением вашей проблемы будет простое назначение страницы `/main` главной страницей?  
Как это сделать можно посмотреть тут:  
`https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/featured-articles/change-homepage`  
501-я ошибка у вас скорее всего из-за строчки `RewriteEngine on`, которая должна стоять до всех правил, а у вас стоит между правилами редиректов.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$|^/$|^index\..+   /main  [L]
```

Comment: Не работает совсем. Выбрасывает 501.

Я так понял, моя задача неразрешима с помощью htaccess

Comment: Вставьте прдложенную часть в самое начало htaccess файла, все должно заработать.

Comment: Вставил.
Выдало Internal Server Error

Comment: Очень странно. Мы указываем серверу, что при открытии главной страницы (или страницы index.*) надо открывать /main и прекращать обработку htaccess. Посмотрите логи. Попробуйте открыть /main прямо из адресной строки, нет ли там ошибки?

Задача именно для htaccess.

Comment: Перепробовал все вамисказанное. Думаю, дело в движке. Он сам УРЛ подменяет и настоящую ссылку я не вижу, потому и не получается ее менять. Потому что даже в пустом файле .htaccess ваш код вообще никак не влияет.